# Geth: flag provided but not defined: -genesis

Tags: go-ethereum, windows

I'm trying to start an ethereum test net on windows 7, but I'm having trouble pointing geth at the genesis block.

This is the command I'm trying:

> geth --identity "Anon" --genesis CustomGenesis.json --rpc --rpcport
>   "8080" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "G:\EthTest" --port "30303"
>   --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 1999 console

The genesis file I'm using is:

> {   "alloc": {   },   "nonce": "0x000000000000002a",   "difficulty":
>   "0x020000",   "mixhash":
>   "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
>   "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>   "timestamp": "0x00",   "parentHash":
>   "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
>   "extraData": "0x",   "gasLimit": "0x2fefd8" }

And it is in the folder I'm trying to launch geth from - it tab completes.

When I run geth with all the above commands except the genesis flag it appears to start and

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}

is visible at localhost:8080 but it doesn't appear to be mining any test ether

Comment: Use `init` instead of `--genesis` and mention the path for genesis file.

Answer (score 9):

Like galahad suggested. Use **init**. It used to be --genesis originally but that was deprecated, now its **init**.

Example:

`./geth init /path/to/genesis.json`

Then exit

From that point forward, your geth node will start with your genesis.

Comment: Thanks! When I use init, Geth itself doesn't give me any errors, but it also doesn't appear to be mining, and localhost:8080 still gives the same error as above?

Comment: You need to start the miner manually. Type `miner.start(1)` in the JavaScript console. `1` can be replaced with the # of mining threads you want.